# Checking file sync using Drive API

Tags: android, google-drive-api

How can I check if the file is uploaded to Google Drive using Google Drive Android API? I was looking [here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos) but the only file missing is the CheckFileSyncStatusActivity.java which, I guess, does the thing I need.

Answer (score 0):

Though its very late to answer but you can make completion events to detect when upload is done to drive.
Here is a google link regarding that [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/completion)